# Preserve row sequence in database

Tags: sql

For example I have a drop-down list of fruits and I want to display them in this particular order:
 - Oranges (0)
 - Grapes (10)
 - Mangoes (20)
 - Apples (30)
My current way of dealing with the problem is to add an index by 10s (so I could insert additional fruits in between). However, this is not very efficient, especially if the number of inserted items would exceed 9 items. Any ideas how I can implement this better?

Comment: Increment by 100's? It's still the same integer column, and so no more or less efficient.

Comment: I would normally have a sort order column with arbitrary values and a secondary alpha-sort on the names if identical sort values exist, but if you must preserve an exact order that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually give the table a `priority` or an `ordering` column, then sorting on that. This way, the ordering is separate from the primary keys, so I can change the ordering and add new items with ease.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a "Categories" table, and include the following fields:
CategoryID
Description
SortOrder (1,2,3,4..)

Then in your Fruits table, add the CategoryID, then join Fruits to Categories and ORDER BY SortOrder, Fruitname...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to create a static order and not change it very much, an `ordering` column as others have suggested is probably the way to go.

If you're likely to change the order a lot and the list is long, that will mean updating every row after the one in question, which will lead to a lot of locking. You could also specify a fruit's following item:

```
 FRUIT     NEXT_FRUIT
 Oranges   Grapes
 Grapes    Mangoes
 Mangoes   Apples
 Apples    (null)
```

Then you can do (Oracle syntax)

```
SELECT level, fruit FROM fruit_table
 START WITH fruit = 'Oranges'
CONNECT BY fruit = PRIOR next_fruit;

     LEVEL FRUIT
---------- ----------
         1 Oranges
         2 Grapes
         3 Mangoes
         4 Apples
```

Then, to add a new item, you only have to insert it and update the one prior to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use rational numbers, but there are more real numbers.

That was a joke, but a float has plenty of space, and to put an entry in, it would just be the midpoint of the two entries it is going between.

Typically for something like this, I use a separate INT SortOrder column (not the primary key) and just do shifts.  If the table is really wide with a lot of entity data in it, move the SortOrder column to a separate table to avoid indexing issues.